# Wordpress invalid style link inserted

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

Wordpress inserts a link tag, where the actual URL is in `data-href` attribute, not `href`:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-editor-font-css'  href="#" data-href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif%3A400%2C400i%2C700%2C700i&#038;ver=5.5' media='all' />
```

I have plugins: Auto Featured Image, Better Search Replace, Child Theme Copy Settings, Mesmerize Companion, Simple Lightbox and the current theme is Mesmerize.

Any idea how to fix it or debug it? It causes multiple errors in the Gutenberg editor.

EDIT: Disabling all the plugins doesn't change it, but it is apparently the theme's fault

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding

```php
<?php
function cns_theme_setup() {
    remove_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'mesmerize_defer_css_scripts', 11 );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cns_theme_setup' );
```

to `functions.php` in my child theme.

This disables Mesmerize theme CSS deferring but makes the error disappear.